# $form->isValid() always returning false after the first submit in Symfony3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

The following is the code of a controller that will generate:

1. A form for entering Jobcode if none is mentioned.
2. Generate a form for entering values into the Jobcard (if Jobcode is present).
3. Generate Jobcard as PDF on submission of form mentioned in 2.

Problem: First time the form (mentioned in 2) is submitted the controller works as desired. But problem starts there after. The aforesaid form on submission yield the following:

1. $form_jobcard->isSubmitted() is true.
2. $form_jobcard->isValid() is false.

`

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Job;
use AppBundle\Entity\ActivityLog;
use AppBundle\Entity\Complaint;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\Response\PdfResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DocumentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/jobcard/{jobcode}", name="jobcard", defaults={"jobcode" = null})
     */
    public function generateJobCardAction($jobcode, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if($jobcode === null){
            $form_jc = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('jobcard'))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('JobCode', TextType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
              'label' => 'Submit'
            ])
            ->getForm();
            $form_jc->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form_jc->isSubmitted() && $form_jc->isValid()) {
                $errors = 0;
                if (!isset($form_jc->getData()["JobCode"]) 
                        || $form_jc->getData()["JobCode"] === "" 
                        || 1 !== preg_match('/^[0-9]{6}-[SCREWTH]$/', strtoupper($form_jc->getData()["JobCode"]))){
                    $errors++;
                    $form_jc->addError(new FormError("Invalid JobCode.")); //Jobcode pattern doesn't match.
                } else if (1 == preg_match('/^[0-9]{6}-[SCREWTH]$/', strtoupper($form_jc->getData()["JobCode"]))){
                    $jcode = strtoupper($form_jc->getData()["JobCode"]);
                    $job = $em->getRepository(Job::class)->findOneBy(array('complaint' => (int)$jcode, 'section' => substr($jcode, 7, 1)));
                    if ($job == NULL){
                        $errors++;
                        $form_jc->addError(new FormError("Invalid JobCode.")); //Job doesn't exist.
                    }
                }
                if (!$errors){
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('jobcard', array("jobcode" => $form_jc->getData()["JobCode"]));
                }
            }
            return $this->render('document/jobcard.html.twig', array("formJobCode" => $form_jc->createView()));
        }
        $jcode = strtoupper($jobcode);
        $job = $em->getRepository(Job::class)->findOneBy(array('complaint' => (int)$jcode, 'section' => substr($jcode, 7, 1)));
        $act = $em->getRepository(ActivityLog::class)->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->where('a.job = :jobid')
                ->setParameter('jobid', $job->getId())
                ->andWhere('a.activityDesc LIKE :activity')
                ->setParameter('activity', '%Jobcard Generated%')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
        $complaint = $em->getRepository(Complaint::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => (int)$jcode));
        $timestamp = (json_decode($complaint->getDatetimeIpJson()))->timestamp;
        $refDate_timestamp = time();
        $location = $complaint->getLocation();
        if(count($act) == 0){
            //if(!isset($jobcardformparams)){$jobcardformparams = null;}
            $form_jobcard = $this->createFormBuilder() //$jobcardformparams, array('allow_extra_fields' => true))
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('jobcard',array('jobcode'=> $jcode)))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('JobReference', TextType::class)
            ->add('Location', TextType::class, array(
                'data' => $location
               ))
            ->add('JobDescription', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
              'label' => 'Submit'
            ])
            ->getForm();
            $form_jobcard->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form_jobcard->isSubmitted() && $form_jobcard->isValid()) {
                $errors = 0;
                if (!isset($form_jobcard->getData()["JobReference"]) || $form_jobcard->getData()["JobReference"] === ""){$errors++;$form->addError(new FormError("Invalid Job Reference No."));}
                if (!isset($form_jobcard->getData()["Location"]) || $form_jobcard->getData()["Location"] === ""){$errors++;$form->addError(new FormError("Invalid Location."));}
                if (!isset($form_jobcard->getData()["JobDescription"]) || $form_jobcard->getData()["JobDescription"] === ""){$errors++;$form->addError(new FormError("Invalid Job Description."));}
                if (!$errors){
                    $jobcardParamArray = array(
                        "JobReference" => $form_jobcard->getData()["JobReference"],
                        "ReferenceDate" => date('d.m.Y', $refDate_timestamp),
                        "ComplaintDate" => date('d.m.Y', $timestamp),
                        "Location" => $form_jobcard->getData()["Location"],
                        "JobDescription" => $form_jobcard->getData()["JobDescription"]
                    );
                    $jobcardParamArray = json_encode(array("activity" => "Jobcard Generated", "document_data" => $jobcardParamArray));
                    $thejob = $em->getRepository(Job::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $jcode));
                    $activityLogEntry = new ActivityLog();
                    $activityLogEntry->setJob($thejob);
                    $activityLogEntry->setTimestamp(new \DateTime());
                    $activityLogEntry->setUser($this->getUser());
                    $activityLogEntry->setActivityDesc($jobcardParamArray);
                    $em->clear();
                    $em->merge($activityLogEntry);
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('jobcard',array('jobcode'=> $jcode)));
                }
            }
            return $this->render('document/jobcard.html.twig', array("formJobCard" => $form_jobcard->createView(), "ComplaintDate" => date('d.m.Y', $timestamp)));
        } else {
            //var_dump(json_decode($act[0]->getActivityDesc(),true));exit();
            $doc_html = $this->renderView('document/jobcard.html.twig', array('jobcardParam' => json_decode($act[0]->getActivityDesc(),true)));
        return new PdfResponse(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($doc_html),
            'jobid-'.$jobcode.'.pdf'
        );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So debut by calling `(string) $form->getErrors(true)`

Comment: @Tokeeen.com: getErrors is so large that it is crashing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Always Provide the entity to `createFormBuilder`

```
$job = new Job();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($job)
        // You code
        ->getForm();
```

Check this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form

Comment: The form that is being generated described in point 2 won't be based on any entity. I think there is a way to build forms without associated entity. But it seems that it is not working in this case or may be it is because of the everchanging route.